# Informix Older than 15 Minutes

Tags: datetime, informix, interval

How can I do this MySQL statement in an IBM Informix?

```
select type, channel, teilnr, starttime, endtime, usedtime, host 
from online_time 
where starttime < DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 15 MINUTE)
order by starttime desc
```

I tried this one in Informix, but it gave a syntax error.

```
select type, channel, teilnr, starttime, endtime, usedtime, host 
from online_time 
where starttime < subdate(CURRENT, INTERVAL "15" MINUTES)
order by starttime desc
```

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42767316/informix-datetime-how-to-subtract-15-minutes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT type, channel, teilnr, starttime, endtime, usedtime, host 
FROM online_time 
WHERE starttime > (CURRENT - 15 UNITS MINUTE) 
ORDER BY starttime DESC
```